# Get flexbox to behave as a table

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a table with `flexbox` but, I have some problems getting it to behave like a table. I can not get it to take only the space required, but still be aligned vertically. As you can see if you run the attached code all column's are taking up the same space. Any suggestions for how I can fix this?

```css
.table {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.table__row {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100%;
    border-bottom:  1px solid #000;
}
.table__row:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.table__row:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: #efefef;
}

.table__column {
    display: flex;
    text-align: left;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    word-break: break-word;
}

.table__header {
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="table__row">
        <div class="table__column table__header">
            ID
        </div>
        <div class="table__column table__header">
            TAG
        </div>
        <div class="table__column table__header">
            USED
        </div>
        <div class="table__column table__header">
            USER
        </div>
        <div class="table__column table__header">
            IP
        </div>
        <div class="table__column table__header">
            DATE
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table__row">
        <div class="table__column">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            newpage
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            0
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            0
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            05.02.2018
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table__row">
        <div class="table__column">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            news
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            0
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            0
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            05.02.2018
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table__row">
        <div class="table__column">
            3
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            rajohan
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            0
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            0
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            05.02.2018
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table__row">
        <div class="table__column">
            4
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            website
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            0
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            0
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            05.02.2018
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table__row">
        <div class="table__column">
            5
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            testtesttesttesttest test test
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            0
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            0
        </div>
        <div class="table__column">
            05.02.2018
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If only there were something other than divs that you could use to make an actual table, that didn't require you to wrangle non-table layout...

Comment: Why don't you make a proper table with css display:table and than display:table cell etc? Or use <table> tags.